# How can I identify that an instance of Boolean SAT problem remains hard or not?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

While I was studying SAT problem and its different instances, in Algorithms for the Satisfiability (SAT) Problem: A Survey by J. Gu et. al [PDF](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a326042.pdf), I came up with this instance, *not mentioned there, but I though of it*, and searched, but could not find anything useful.

And the instance,

Suppose $f$ is a boolean function in $n$ boolean variables, but with this extra property, that $f$ is increasing. I have thought of $n$ boolean variables, $X_1, \ldots, x_n$ as representation of subsets of a set with $n$ elements, and if some  subset like $X$ satisfies $f$, then all $X \subseteq Y$ satisfy $f$, too. *What I want is finding the minimal $X$ where $f$ satisfies it, but not any $Z$ where $Z \subsetneq X$?*

Is this problem still hard?

Clarification: Due to a comment, *increasing* is a term I used here, and the reason I used it is as follows. For a set of $n$ elements, its subsets can be represented by an $n$ bits register, the input to $f$. *I assume that if $f(X) = 1$, then for any $Y$ such that $X \subseteq Y$, $f(Y) =1 $*.

P.S. If I consider the $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ as a number, then increasing property of $f$ helps solving it in polynomial time, just a binary search suffices! So, I made it a little bit hard.

Any help, even offers of search terms is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean for a Boolean function of several Boolean variables to be increasing?

Comment: Clarifications added.

Comment: Note that *the* minimal $X$ with $f(X) = 1$ might not exists: there might be one *more than one* minimal $X$. So, do you *assume* there is a unique minimal $X$ with $f(X) = 1$, or do you want to find only *a* minimal $X$, or do you want to find *all* minimal $X$?

Comment: Assuming you want to find only *a* minimal $X$, this is rather trivial. Start with $S = \{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. If $f(S) = 0$, then $f(X) = 0$ for all $X$. Otherwise, see if $f(S \setminus \{X_i\}) = 1$ for some $X_i \in S$. If there is no such $i$, $S$ is minimal with $f(S) = 1$. If there is such an $i$, continue with $S \setminus \{X_i\}$ instead of $S$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, You are right about a naive algorithm for finding it, it is of complexity \mathcal{O}(2^n)$ which is not clearly a polynomial time algorithm. I am rather interested in knowing whether it is NP-hard or not?

Comment: What is "it" here - what is the (decision)problem that you are considering?

Comment: And my algorithm finds a minimal set in quadratic time.

Comment: The decision instance is that $X$ is a minimal point for $f$ such that $f(X) = 1$ and for any $Z \subsetneq X$, $f(Z) = 0$.

Comment: Oh, so you're given $f$ and $X$, but *not* that $f$ is increasing?

Comment: @Magdiragdag Yeah, your algorithm is quadratic, but **does not solve** the problem, I was just confused with small and big $x$s, $X = (x_1, \ldots , x_n)$ in problem statement.

Comment: No, I know that $f$ is increasing, I know $f$, and I am given $X$, but I want to decide whether or not, $X$ is such a minimal set? (If $f(X)=0$, it is clear, but for $f(X) = 1$, how many other subsets I shall check?

Comment: I guess I am (still) unclear on what the problem is. Why can't you just check all the subsets $X'$ of $X$ obtained by leaving out a single element. If they all have $f(X') = 0$, then $X$ is minimal; otherwise it isn't. So you check $|X|$ subsets.

Comment: That is right. But it is time consuming! A set with $\ell$ elements has $2^{\ell}$ subsets! This is going to be super increasing! I suspect that this problem is $\mathbf{NP}-hard$, but no proofs!

Comment: No, you only check the ones where you leave out a single element of $X$. There are $|X|$ of those.

Comment: Hmm, Let's see! I will check for $X = (1, \ldots, 1)$, it should be one, if not, I am done! Next, I will recurse by dropping an element and check it again, at worst case for a set $X$, I shall check $\vert X \vert$, till the end, it is quadratic! Thanks

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thanks, Would you mind adding an answer so I can accept it. Again, thank you. I was totally confused about this problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll do so. Glad to have cleared up some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that there may be more than one minimal $X$ satisfying $f(X) = 1$.

If we want to find just a single minimal $X$, then it can be done as follows.

Start with $S = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. If $f(S) = 0$, then $f$ is identically $0$ and no minimal $X$ with $f(X) = 1$ exists. Otherwise, check $f(S \setminus \{ x_i \})$ for all $x_i \in S$. If there are *all* $0$, then $S$ is minimal with $f(S) = 1$. Otherwise, consider one such $x_i$ with $f(S \setminus \{ x_i \}) = 1$ and continue with $S \setminus \{ x_i \}$ instead of $S$.

Every step, you check at most $n$ elements (one less every step, but let's overestimate) and there are at most $n$ steps (because every step one element drops out of $S$). So this takes $n^2$ evaluations of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to find such a subset of the inputs. Trivially, $f$ is increasing if $f(Y) = 1$ but for any $X \subset Y$ with $X \neq Y$ and $f(X) = 0$. This problem is just the standard SAT problem, so it is still NP-Complete. In practice, you may find many cases where you can check substantially fewer inputs. However, note that there are $2^{n}$ possible subsets, and $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{|Y|}{i}$, for $n < |Y|$, will grow pretty quickly.

Also, even if you have the constraint that $X \subset Y$ (a proper subset) with $f(X) = 1$ implies that $f(Y) = 1$, you still have at most $2^{n} - 1$ possible subsets of $Y$ to check, as $\sum_{i=0}^{|Y|-1} \binom{|Y|}{i} = 2^{|Y|} - 1$.

Comment: I suspected that this is $\mathbb{NP}-hard$, but this condition was bothering. That's right, I shall find the point and it is SAT! The structure, increasing in the sense above, does not help anymore. Thanks.